# Generic term for Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

In calculus we have the concept of a Limit of a function (I mean the one described [there])[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)).

I consider limits to be something that helps us to consider a function from somewhat another perspective. For example if in a function the value is not defined at some point *x*, then it might be defined at the limit of that function.

So I am wondering if there is some generic term for entities like limits? Are there any other entities like that in other branches of maths? Can we probably say that limits are also functions, taking other functions as arguments?

Comment: This might be too advanced for you but still you can have a look. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

Comment: Nets generalise sequences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)

Comment: Functions (of various kinds) that take other functions as arguments are known as [functionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) - although the usage of this term varies in different disciplines (see the linked article). You can dream up a functional which fills in the discontinuities of a partial function, but I don't think it is of any great interest: in "nature", functions tend to come defined with the "right" domain of definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can think of limits as being functions which take in other functions of arguments. Here's an example: Let $H$ be the set of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the limit of the function is defined at each point. Of course, continuous functions are contained in $H$. But also, functions which have 'holes' will be contained in $H$ as well.

One can then define a limit as being a function from $H$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Fix $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and define $L_a: H\to \mathbb{R}$ to be the map
$$
L_a[f(x)] = \lim_{x\to a}f(x).
$$
In this way, we are thinking of $L_a$ as being a function which acts on functions and evaluates them as real numbers. I would refer to this object as a **functional**, which (to my understanding) is just a fancy way of saying this function takes functions as its input and evaluates them as real numbers. Here are some other examples of mappings whose inputs are functions. Some of these will be familiar (assuming you have taken Calculus). I will be less specific with what the domains are from here. For now, just assume that the domain is chosen so that the mapping can actually exist.
\begin{align}
&(1). \text{The maximum operator: } M[f] = \max_{a \leq x \leq b}{f(x)}\\ \\
&(2). \text{The derivative operator: } D[f] =\left.\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]\right|_{x=a} = f'(a).\\ \\ 
&(3). \text{The integral operator: } I[f] = \int_a^b f(x)dx.\\ \\
&(4). \text{ For a fixed function } g \text{, set } I_g[f] = I[fg] = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx.\\ \\
&(5). \text{ The Laplace Transform: } \mathcal{L}\{f\}(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt. \\ \\
&(6). \text{ The Fourier Transform: } \mathcal{F}[f](s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi i(s\cdot x)}dx.
\end{align}

So the short answer is, yes. This is just a short list of examples, and these are examples of ones that are relevant to what I do. I'm sure that many other branches of math will have other interesting examples.

Comment: The Expected Value also fits this list pretty well.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why Expected Value is also functional? Expected value takes random value as an argument. Can we consider random value a function?

Comment: Since these can all be undefined, we should consider them _partial functions_ and not functions proper.  It is incorrect to call $L_a : H \to \mathbb R$ a function.

Comment: The mapping $L_a$ is well-defined on $H$, since $H$ is defined to be the set of functions for which limits exist at each point in $\mathbb{R}$. So by our choice of domain, $L_a$ is certainly a function.